# error running scala on Netbeans V.7.4

Tags: scala, netbeans

I have trouble while trying to compile and run a scala program using Netbeans IDE 7.4

log error below this :

```
Compiling 1 source file to F:\Bahasa_Scala\2016\Juni\ScalaApplication2\build\classes
F:\Bahasa_Scala\2016\Juni\ScalaApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:405: The following error occurred while executing this line:
F:\Bahasa_Scala\2016\Juni\ScalaApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:238: bad option: '-make:transitive'
BUILD FAILED (total time: 0 seconds)
```

I have searched and followed the instruction from here [help1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629006/error-while-building-project-in-netbeans) but it's still not working for me.

source/binary format is JDK 8.

any suggestion?
thanks

Comment: I am not sure about Netbeans, but try scala [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org/).

Comment: why you dont sure?
scala sbt? what kind of those? hehehe

Answer (score 0):

the solutions right below this :

1. open F:\Bahasa_Scala\2016\Juni\ScalaApplication2\nbproject\build-impl.xml:238 (on line 1)
2. after that remove **-make:transitivie** and then the code would be (on line 3)

after that, clean and build and run. happy coding scala, guys!

[code link here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0Bxn6E8TrwP2ASkJKbURzVzZhV1U)